# On back navigation samsung mobile showing black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-camera

I am adding camera functionality in my app. Capturing image from camera and to preview the image is working fine.But when I am pressing the back navigation from navigation bar to back from preview activity to camera activity it showing the black screen. I am able to capture the image but showing black screen. This issues is showing only on Samsung mobile what issues can be there any idea ?

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can get idea of what is wrong??

Comment: "I am able to capture the image" – do you mean that after you step back from the preview activity, camera activity is black but working?